# Is NVIDIA GeForce GT 635M suitable for Deep Learning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, pytorch

My GPU model is NVIDIA GeForce GT 635M and on NVIDIA site it is said that this GPU  is CUDA-enabled. Can I use TensorFlow or PyTorch or any other kind of Deep Learning platforms with this GPU or it is not suitable?

Comment: If you're unsure how much you're prepared to invest you can play around with GPU nodes on some cloud platform to get a feel how much GPU power you need.

Answer (score 6):

**TensorFlow and PyTorch will ignore this GPU and use the CPU instead. Maybe you can find other ML libraries which would work with it.**

Any GPU can be used for Deep Learning training. You can even train only on your CPU. This is mostly true for using TensorFlow and PyTorch as well, but there are caveats as discussed later.

As for their suitability for the task, it is true that some GPUs are better than others, for various reasons. One would clearly be just the performance aspect - the more powerful the GPU, the quicker the training. Another is the CUDA capability of the given GPU, which you have mentioned in your question. The GPU you mention, NVIDIA GeForce GT 653M, [is CUDA enabled](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), but has the Compute Capability of only 2.1 which is on the low end. This also means that [you won't be able to use TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) or [PyTorch](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html) because they require >= 3.0 Compute Capability (thanks to [janneb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75652/janneb) for pointing that out). You will still be able to use them, but not with your GPU, only with CPU.

It is not a bad GPU to train on, mainly if you are just beginning with Deep Learning, but it is not the best either. You do not need to worry about not being able to use some software or not being able to train some networks because of that though.

Comment: tensorflow requires compute capability 3.0 or better, and IIRC pytorch as well.

Comment: @janneb Ah, my mistake, thanks for pointing that out. I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Not any GPU can be used, AMD GPUs for example cannnot be usually used, as most frameworks only support CUDA.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro The first sentence talks about the Deep Learning training in general (without any frameworks) which is possible to be conducted on any GPU whatsoever. The need for CUDA enabled GPUs is specified later.

Comment: Thank you all for the consistent answer. __||